# Why does the last drag event that fires have negative x and y coordinates?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ypYTT/1/

As you can see, I have a very simple markup, with an image that (eventually) will be dragged around changing the background position.
If you drag a bit you can see the x,y coordinates of the event fired as you would expect, but the last event fired always seems to have a negative X,Y coordinate pair, which seems to be dependent on the size of the "result" jsfiddle frame.

What are these coordinates from the last event, and why are they negative?  They are being fired from a "drag" type event, but only as the final mouseup happens (no mouseup is fired from the drag, because that wouldn't make sense).

Markup HTML

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" />
```

CSS

```
img {
    background: linear-gradient( to left top, blue, red);
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    margin:20px;
}
```

JavaScript

```
$('img').on('dragstart drag dragstop', function(e){
    console.log(e.originalEvent);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an error in your code. 'dragstop' should be 'dragend'.

Please see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ypYTT/3/

I can still see the negative values appears, but they are not the last value received by the console, so it may be fixing your problem.

The code is now as follows:

```
$('img').on('dragstart drag dragend', function(e){
console.log(e.originalEvent);
});
$('img').on('mouseup', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```

Comment: while useful (I was wondering why no drags top was finishing), I still would like to know where the negative coords are coming from.  if you're listening for he drag event to move it, I suppose you can always look for the coords to be >0, but it seems hacks to do so.

Comment: I totally agree, and I can't yet explain what's going on with your script. Will let you know if I found the solution.